# Record Editor Cobol To Csv

Tags: csv, mainframe

I have a problem that I'm facing with Record Editor and trying to convert COBOL data and Copybook files to CSV. I'm stuck at a point where "Generate Code for Cobol Copybook creates a preview that is accurate, but I'm not able to export it because the only way I can get it accurate is by using "Unknown File Format", "Fixed Length Binary" file structure with record length of "XXX" or "422". Maybe someone knows how to fix this? or how to approach this situation?

[Initial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9F5oQ.png)
[Unknown File Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edhHD.png)
[Final](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joNsD.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possible solutions

- Update the Generated java code and set the recordLength
- Add a Filler to the copybook to increase its length to 422.

---

### Use setRecordLength option

In the generated code, you can add a **setRecordLength** call to force JRecord to use a length greater than in the copybook

i.e. there will be code like

```
ICobolIOBuilder ioBldr = JRecordInterface1.COBOL
                .newIOBuilder(new ByteArrayInputStream(cobolCopybook.getBytes()), "COMPANY-RECORD")
```

You can add a **setRecordLength** method to the call

```
ICobolIOBuilder ioBldr = JRecordInterface1.COBOL
        .newIOBuilder(new ByteArrayInputStream(cobolCopybook.getBytes()), "COMPANY-RECORD")
            .setRecordLength(422)
```

#### Update copybook

you can add a filler to the copybook to increase the record to a length of 422

Answer (score 2):

It looks like I figured out what was the problem, the copybook was not defined with an ending filler field that would be sufficient to create 422 record length.